# copy data from another table which doesn't exist in the first one.

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

How can we copy data from one table into another table which doesn't exist in the first one.  In table one of the column is primary key.

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM db2.table; 
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '100001' for key 'id_UNIQUE'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the predicate [**`NOT IN`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) to do so like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT * 
FROM db2.table2 
WHERE table1ReferenceID NOT IN(SELECT id_UNIQUE FROM table1);
```

This will checks whether this `table1ReferenceID` found in the first table or nor. Therefore, the `SELECT` clause will select all the rows from the second tables except those that is already presented in the first table table1.

**Note that:** the column `table1ReferenceID` is the reference of the `id_UNIQUE` in the second table.

Other alternatives for this, is to `LEFT JOIN` as suggested by [**@HamletHakobyan**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14729681/722783) and `NOT EXISTS`.

- [**See it in action**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d386/1)

Comment: some explanation would help this answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT T1.*
FROM db2.table T1
    LEFT JOIN table T2
       ON T1.Id = T2.Id
WHERE T2.Id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE [primary_key_table1] not IN (SELECT [primary_key_table2] FROM [table2])
```

so i suggest something like

```
INSERT INTO table (SELECT * FROM db2.table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table));
```